# Kali Linux (old install) will not boot

Tags: boot, kali-linux, data-recovery, initramfs

Thank you to everyone for the advice, I have tried everything I could think of but nothing seems to solve the problem. I will format the drive and reuse it. I have this horrible feeling the drive may have a BTC wallet on it from 2010 when they cost nothing, it's likely to contain something, it's a shame but sometimes that's the way the cookie crumbles!

I need help with a old (6 yrs ) install of Kali Linux which now fails to boot. The OS does not need to be fixed, as all I want to do is recover some photo files on the drive. These photos can not be replaced and hold great sentimental valve to me as they were taken at my Nan;'s funeral.

I know someone will say why was you using Kali as your main system, the answer is because I didn’t understand what it was back then and thought it was a reliable system like any other Linux distro... I have learnt a lot since then... the issue...

It will not boot.  It gets though grub no problem and asks me if it should start normally or in recovery but whatever I choose it always ends the same way... in initrams this is the output

Mount: :dev/mapper/cuckoo-root on /root failed: Invalid argument
mount: /dev on root/dev failed: No such file or directory target file system
 doesn’t have requested/sbin/init. No init found.
Try passing init= Bootarg. mod
probe: module echo-Orion not found in modules.dep

BusyBox v1.20.2 (Debian 1:1.20.0-7) built-in-shell (ash) 
enter —help for help 
/bin/sh: can’t access tty; job control turned off

(initrams)

This version of BusyBox does not have fsck included and if I type exit it instantly shuts down and won’t allow terminal

If I put disk in another machine and use Fdisk -l /dev/sub I get the following

Disk /dev/sdb: 232.9GiB 250059349504 bytes , 488397167 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 *512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 33553920 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000583aa

Device Boot Start End Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1 * 2048 499711 497664 243M 83 Linux
/dev/sdb2 501758 488396799 487895042 232.7G 5 Extended
/dev/sda5 501760 488396799 487895040 232.7G 8e Linux LVM

Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary

If I run sudo fsck -f /dev/sdb I get the following out put

Fsck from until-Linux 2.31.1
e2fsck 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
fsck.ext2: Superblock invalid, trying backup block...
fsck.ext2: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdb

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem. If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/etc3/etx4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with alternative superblock:

e2fsck -b 8193 
or
e2fsck -b 32768

Found a dis partition table in /dev/sdb

I have tried both these and every other backup superblock but the system crashes on reboot so don’t know if they just don’t work or are not being used because of the crash...

I have had to type this all by hand on a iPhone so please excuse any mistakes I think it’s all accurate. I don’t know what to do next I have read lots of articles online but none have the exact same issue.

Any help is very much appreciated

Thank you

------------------------OUTPUT ON BOOT-------------------------

This is the output on the screen   \
Mount: :dev/mapper/cuckoo-root on /root failed: Invalid argument
mount: /dev on root/dev failed: No such file or directory target file system doesn’t have requested/sbin/init.
No init found.
Try passing init= Bootarg.
mod probe: module echo-Orion not found in modules.dep
BusyBox v1.20.2 (Debian 1:1.20.0-7) built-in-shell (ash) enter help for help

/bin/sh: can’t access tty; job control turned off (initrams)

--------------------- TRYING TO MOUNT -----------------------

## print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 231475088

## JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 2806

## EXT4-fs (dm-0): error loading journal

mount /mnt/1: can’t read superblock on /dev/mapper/cuckoo-root

Edit notes

I have edited the above so it now explains the issue better

Comment: Please click [edit] and add the content from your Comments above into the original question, then delete the comments. Everything about the problem should be in the Question; please use [edit] instead of Add Comments.

Comment: How was that drive partitioned? ext4, ext3, other? When you attach the old drive to another PC and power up, what does fsck find? https://www.linode.com/docs/quick-answers/linux/how-to-use-fsck-to-fix-disk-problems may help. Please advise results with [edit].

Comment: Sorry it wouldn't let me edit last night. I have updated the OP it now includes all the info, thanks for the advice :)

Comment: Could you try adding some formatting to the outputs you get please, so it will be easier to read?

Comment: How do you mean like [CODE] The ouput [/CODE] I tried and it doesnt work like on a forum

Comment: Editing tips are at https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code .   For example, two blank spaces (or more) immediately before a hard return are required for Stack Exchange sites to show that hard return.

Comment: To format your code, select it, then click the {} button.

Comment: okay really sorry this is the first time an email has alerted me to new activity in days, I will edit tonight im at work and cant do this on a IPhone.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to boot to Kali from your internal drive to do what you want.

Boot the laptop from an USB Live Distro and access the laptop's drive via the Live Distro. From there, you can copy the contents to another external drive.

Otherwise, open the laptop, remove the drive, insert it into an USB enclosure and make it an external drive (whose contents can be accessed from any other computer).

Comment: I have tried to plug drive into my server and into an external hard drive cage but i get an error, Ive updated the OP with details of error